# Linked List Bug - Unknown Numbers and Bugged Function

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I've been brushing up on data structures recently, specifically linked list, and was having some trouble determining the origin of some numbers. The  number -2147483648 is shown twice each time the list is updated and it is always at the end of the list. I have no idea where this number comes from, but it is always present. It is worth nothing that when adding a new element to the tail of the list, the new value is placed between the two unknown nodes. I will highlight an example in the output. It is also worth noting that the list only accounts for one of the values. I will also highlight this in the output.

Lastly, the remove function, which removes a specific node fails to remove any node that isn't specified as the head or tail. If i try to remove any node in the middle, the node will fail to  be removed.

Any help determining the significance of these numbers and a fix regarding the remove function will appreciated. Thanks!

Programs Output:

```
//**with the two unknown numbers at the end, the list amounts to 10 elements,
 but the length variable returns 9. It is like this throughout the entire process**//

Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:9

//**adding the element 9 to the tail of the list places it between the two unknown numbers**//

Updated Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,9,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:10

//removes the tail node by calling removeTail function
Updated Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:9

//adds a new head node by calling insertHead function
Updated Linked List Content:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:10

//removes the head node by calling removeHead function
Updated Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:9

//adds a new node in the middle of the list by calling insert function
Updated Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:10

//**attempts to use the remove function to remove the extra 5 but it doesn't work**//
Updated Linked List Content:[1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,8,-2147483648,-2147483648]
Linked List Length:10

//clears the entire list by calling the clearList function
Updated Linked List Content:[] 
Linked List Length:0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The Node class

```
 public class ListNode {
    private int data;                   //the number or data that the node holds
    public ListNode next;              //a pointer to the next node
    public ListNode prev;               //a pointer pointing to the previous node

    //constructors
    public ListNode (int data, ListNode prev, ListNode next){
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.prev = prev;
    }
    public ListNode (int data){
        this.data = data;
        prev = null;
        next = null;
    }

    //methods (getters and setters)
    public int getData(){               //getter methods for the data variable
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(int data){      //initializes that data object
        this.data = data;
    }

    public ListNode getPrev(){return prev;}

    public ListNode getNext(){return next;}

    public void setPrev(ListNode where){prev = where;}

    public void setNext(ListNode where){next = where;}
    }
```

The List class

```
  public class LinkedLists {
    private ListNode head;              //the first node in the list
    private ListNode tail;              //the last node in the list
    private int length;                 //the length of the linked list

    //specific constructor
    //creating the list
    public LinkedLists(){
        head = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
        tail = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, head, null);
        head.setNext(tail);
        length = 0;
    }

    //get the value at a given position
    public int getValue(int position){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    //find the position of the head value that is equal to the given value

    public int getPosition(int data){
        //go looking for data
        ListNode temp = head;
        int pos = 0;
        while (temp != null){
            if (temp.getData() == data){
                //return the position if found
                return pos;
            }
            pos = pos+ 1;
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        //else return some larger value
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    //return the current length of the LinkedList
    public int length(){
        return length;
    }

    //add a new value to the front of the list
    public void insertHead(int newValue){
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newValue, head, head.getNext());
        newNode.getNext().setPrev(newNode);
        head.setNext(newNode);
        length = length + 1;
    }

    //add a new value to the list at a given position
    //all the values at the position to the end move over to make room
    public void insert(int data, int position){
        //fix the position
        if (position < 0){
            position = 0;
        }
        if (position > length){
            position = length;
        }
        //if the list is empty, make it be the only element
        if (head == null){
            head = new ListNode(data);
            tail = head;
        }
        //if adding at the front of the list
        else if (position == 0){
            ListNode temp = new ListNode(data);
            temp.next = head;
            head = temp;
        }
        //else find the correct position and insert
        else{
            ListNode temp = head;
            for (int i = 1; i < position; i = i+1){
                temp = temp.getNext();
            }
            ListNode newNode = new ListNode(data);
            newNode.next = temp.next;
            newNode.prev = temp;
            newNode.next.prev = newNode;
            temp.next = newNode;
        }
        //the list is now one value longer
        length ++;
    }

    //add a new value to the rear of the list
    public void insertTail(int newValue){
        ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newValue, tail.getPrev(),tail);
        newNode.getPrev().setNext(newNode);
        tail.setPrev(newNode);
        length++;
    }

    //remove the value at a given position
    public void remove(int position){
        //if the position is less than 0, remove the value at position 0
        if (position < 0){
            position = 0;
        }
        //if the position is greater than 0, remove the value at the last position
        if (position > 0){
            position = length - 1;
        }
        //if the list is empty, do nothing
        if (head == null){
            return;
        }
        //if removing the head element
        if (position ==0){
            head = head.getNext();
            if (head == null){
                tail = null;
            }
            //else advance to the correct position and remove
            else{
                ListNode temp = head;
                for (int i = 1; i< position; i++){
                    temp = temp.getNext();
                }
                temp.getNext().setPrev(temp.getPrev());
                temp.getPrev().setNext(temp.getNext());
            }
            //reduce the length  of the list
            length --;
        }
    }
    //remove a node matching a specified node from the list
    public synchronized void removeMatched(ListNode node){
        if (head == null){
            return;
        }
        if (node.equals(head)){
            head = head.getNext();
            if (head == null){
                tail = null;
            }
            return;
        }
        ListNode p = head;
        while (p!= null){
            if (node.equals(p)){
                p.prev.next = p.next;
                p.next.prev = p.prev;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    //remove the head value from the list
    //if the list is empty, do nothing
    public int removeHead(){
        if (length ==0){
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        ListNode save = head.getNext();
        head.setNext(save.getNext());
        save.getNext().setPrev(head);
        length --;
        return save.getData();
    }

    ////remove the tail value from the list
    //if the list is empty, do nothing
    public int removeTail(){
        if (length ==0){
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        ListNode save = tail.getPrev();
        tail.setPrev(save.getPrev());
        save.getPrev().setNext(tail);
        length --;
        return save.getData();
    }

    //return a string representation of this collection
    public String toString(){
        String result = "[]";
        if (length == 0){
            return result;
        }
        result = "[" + head.getNext().getData();
        ListNode temp = head.getNext().getNext();
        while(temp != null){
            result += "," + temp.getData();
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return result + "]";
    }

    //remove everything  from the list
    public void clearList(){
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        length = 0;
    }
}
```

The main file

```
   public class main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Linked list declaration
        LinkedLists linkedlist = new LinkedLists();

        //add more elements to the list
        linkedlist.insert(0,1);
        linkedlist.insert(1,2);
        linkedlist.insert(2,3);
        linkedlist.insert(3,4);
        linkedlist.insert(4,5);
        linkedlist.insert(5,6);
        linkedlist.insert(6,7);
        linkedlist.insert(7,8);
        linkedlist.insert(8,9);

        //display linked list contents and its length
        System.out.println("Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());


        //add an element to the end of the list and also print out its length
        //O(n)
        linkedlist.insertTail(9);
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());
        //the new list should now be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]


        //remove the element at the end of the list that was just added
        linkedlist.removeTail();
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());


        //add an element to the head of the list
        linkedlist.insertHead(0);
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());
        //the new list should be: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]


        //delete that same element from the front of the list
        linkedlist.removeHead();
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());



        //Insert an element into the middle of the list
        linkedlist.insert(5,6);
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());



        //remove a value into the middle of the list
        //BUG INSIDE THE REMOVE FUNCTION!!! THE VALUE REMAINS INSIDE THE LIST
        linkedlist.remove(6);
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());
        //the 5 should be removed from the list



        //clear the entire list
        linkedlist.clearList();
        System.out.println("Updated Linked List Content:" + linkedlist);
        System.out.println("Linked List Length:" + linkedlist.length());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two unknown numbers you are seeing in your list are there because of

```
head = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
tail = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, head, null);
```

Your insertTail() method is inserting node wrongly

```
public void insertTail(int newValue){
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newValue, tail.getPrev(),tail);
    newNode.getPrev().setNext(newNode);
    tail.setPrev(newNode);
    length++;
}
```

This will always add new node between Last and Second Last Node. You need to modify it something like this to add at end

```
public void insertTail(int newValue){
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newValue, tail,null);
    tail.setNext(newNode);
    tail = newNode;
    length++;
}
```

Similarly removing an item from tail shall be done

```
public int removeTail(){
    if (length ==0){
        return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    ListNode returnNode = tail;
    tail.getPrev().setNext(null);
    tail = tail.getPrev();
    length --;
    return returnNode.getData();
}
```

Comment: There are multiple questions to be answered here.. This feels like a comment rather than an answer. Don't be in a hurry to post half baked answers..

Comment: I believe these two statements are the reason for every question OP is asking because all others are just about correct usage of APIs

Comment: "//**adding the element 9 to the tail of the list places it between the two unknown numbers**//" or "//**attempts to use the remove function to remove the extra 5 but it doesn't work**//". I don't see how your answer addresses these concerns. It is no way implied by your answer. A question however straightforward is still a question and needs to be addressed for an answer to be complete. Just my two cents.

Comment: That is because of adding it wrongly. If you will look at the code of insertTail method, it is adding elements between last and second last element

Comment: I don't think you got my point. Whatever the reason, your initial post did not address it. All you addressed was the first paragraph of the question in your initial post. and left out the rest of the question unanswered..

Comment: Thanks for the help but I have some questions. I still haven't gotten an answer for the remove() method. This method is different from the removeTail() because it specifies the removal of a node that is not the head nor tail (somewhere between). Also, I don't understand how head = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, null, null);
tail = new ListNode(Integer.MIN_VALUE, head, null); causes the random  numbers

Comment: You are specifically passing value for head and tail as `Integer.MIN_VALUE` which is `-2147483648`. For remove method, please debug your code and see where you are making a mistake.